# I am trying to load a picture from my galary into a form using Android

Tags: android, button, parse-platform, android-imageview

I have an image view together with a button, so when I click the button I get all to select the image but it is not loaded onto the view. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.... Kindly see attached the code, I am fairly new in using Android.
I want the the image view to have the image that I picked from the galary. I might be missing a small or very big piece of code I am not sure. Please help

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPickImage) {
                onImageGalleryClicked(v);
            }
        }

        public void onImageGalleryClicked(View v) {
            Intent pick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String picture = pictureDirectory.getPath();

            Uri data = Uri.parse(picture);

            pick.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
            //Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT to handle back the result when the image is picked from the Image Gallery
            startActivityForResult(pick, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Everything Okay
                if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS) {
                    Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                    InputStream inputStream;
                    try {
                        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage);
                        Bitmap selectedImages = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        image.setImageBitmap(selectedImages);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Unable to load image",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the xml on my machine.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnPickImage"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPickImage"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnPickImage"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnPickImage" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPickImage"
            android:onClick="pickImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtLoadImage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onActivityResult(), first line should be

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

Comment: I have that as the first line in that method.

Comment: You wrote requestCode instead of resultCode.

Comment: Ow wow how can I miss that, thank you. But still after replacing with requestCode it still doesn't show the image in the view.

Comment: Thank you so much , I just needed to give it a bit of time to load..... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `image` being declared.

You need something like this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

before calling your

```
image.setImageBitmap(selectedImages);
```

Comment: I have it declared globally and initialized on the onCreate() method, Sorry I should've explained that when asking the question.

Comment: So the imageView does not do anything at all, and no error? Have you checked if the passed Bitmap is null?

Comment: It loaded , the mistake was on @Xiaoyu 's solution, Thank you so much :)